# Java class declared with strictfp modifier fails test with Modifier.isStrict(int)

Tags: java, strictfp

To be clear, this question is strictly hypothetical.  Personally, I have no Real World need for this behaviour; I discovered it accidentally.

Inspired by: [How to make a (static) initializer block strictfp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145114/how-to-make-a-static-initializer-block-strictfp)

If I declare a Java class with `strictfp` modifier:

```
public strictfp class PublicStrictfpClass
{
    public double f() { return 2d / 3d; }
}
```

... then I test using `Modifier.isStrict(int)`:

```
public static void main(String[] argArr)
{
    if (! Modifier.isStrict(PublicStrictfpClass.class.getModifiers()))
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unreachable code");
    }
}
```

The above code fails: Method `main()` throws `IllegalStateException`.  I tried a class declaration with *and* without method `PublicStrictfpClass.f()` -- both fail.

Do I misunderstand ... ?

- The `strictfp` modifier when used in class declarations?
- The method `Modifier.isStrict(int)`?

I am running this code from Linux using the latest patch for OpenJDK 8.

Finally, I did a bunch of Googling before asking this question.  The keyword `strictfp` is very rare in the wild!

Comment: Hmm, `isStrict()` just does bitmasking, but `getModifiers()` is a native method / hotspot intrinsic. Maybe it worked at one point, then stopped working and nobody noticed or cared (or it never worked).

Comment: It's not only rare in the wild, it's functionality was also removed in Java 17, so it should be avoided all together.

Comment: I doubt either that it never worked, or that it stopped working at one point; rather, the spec for what it does is subtly different to what one might think it should do. Specifically, it refers to the modifiers in *the class*, not in *the source code*, and the `strictfp` modifier ceases to be attached to the class during compilation. Per `javap -c`, it seems as if the compiler outputs bytecode in which the `strictfp` modifier applies to every constructor and method in the class, but not the class itself.

Comment: Well I don't *actually* think it was broken from the beginning, but since we're putting this much effort into `strictfp`, why not offer some wild theories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because the [class modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1) in the class file do not include the `strictfp` (don't know why, must ask Java developers). This is what the `getModifiers()` method looks into, [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers--) states: *"The modifiers consist of the Java Virtual Machine's constants for `public`, `protected`, `private`, `final`, `static`, `abstract` and `interface`".* (so no mentioning of `strictfp`)

You can still get the modifiers of the method `f`. The method modifiers do include `strictfp`:

```
Modifier.isStrict(PublicStrictfpClass.class.getMethod("f").getModifiers())
```

Comment: Docs link for the quote: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers--